# Are holomorphic functions analytic also in infinite dimensions?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analytic-functions

One of the first results of complex analysis is that differentiability is a very strong condition: If $U\subseteq \Bbb C$ is open, then every complex differentiable function $f:U\to\Bbb C$ is automatically analytic.

> If $X,Y$ are complex Banach spaces, $U\subseteq X$ open and $f:U\to Y$ differentiable, is $f$ analytic?

It makes sense to define what analytic means in this context. We say that a map $f:U\to Y$ is analytic if each point $x_0\in U$ admits a neighbourhood $U'$ so that
$$f\lvert_{U'} (x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n,$$
where $a_n : \times^n X\to Y$ is a continuous $n$-multilinear map (in particular $a_0$ is a constant element of $Y$) and the sum converges uniformly on $U'$. $a_n(x-x_0)^n$ is then shorthand for $a_n(x-x_0,...,x-x_0)$.

Comment: The main problem is that you didn't define $a_n (x-x_0)^n$ in a relevant way. In finite dimension that $f$ is analytic $\Bbb{C}^M \to \Bbb{C}$ means for all $y$ for $\|x\|$ small enough $f(y+x)=\displaystyle\sum_{\beta\in \Bbb{Z}_{ \ge 0}^M} a_\beta(y) \prod_{m=1}^M x_m^{\beta_m}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The finite dimensional case $\Bbb C^M\to\Bbb C^N$ is covered by this definition, and any other formulations I could think of, like for example the $v^*\circ f\lvert_{X_{fin}\cap U}$ being analytic for all $v^*\in Y^*$ and $X_{fin}$ finite dimensional affine subspaces in $X$, are implied by this definition.